# Это членимое сочетание?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, члены-предложения, подлежащее

Входит ли в подлежащее слова "группа", "стая", "толпа"? Например, "группа музыкантов играет" / "стая волков играет" / "толпа ребят играет"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечая на вопрос «Входит ли в подлежащее слова "группа", "стая", "толпа"?», думаю, что да, несомненно. Эти слова стоят в именительном падеже, согласуются со сказуемым и являются, так сказать, **опорными**. К таким словам относятся ***ряд, большинство, меньшинство, часть, множество, масса, уйма, пара, тройка, сотня*** и пр.
А вот позиция "музыкантов", "волков" и "ребят" может вызвать дискуссию. По-простому они отвечают на вопрос "кого?" и, казалось бы, выполняют роль дополнения.
Но всё же в силу синтаксических соображений такие сочетания представляются как **нечленимые**, то есть оба слова входят в состав подлежащего.

[**Подлежащее, способы его выражения**](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#311) (Грамота.ру)

> **Подлежащее — словосочетание:**
>
> **1.** Подлежащее — **фразеологически свободное, но синтаксически связанное** словосочетание:
> <...>
> **2)** слово с количественным значением (колич. числит., сущ., наречие) + сущ. в Р. п.:
> *Прошло **три года**.
>
> **Куча вещей** скопилась в углу.*

[**Единственное и множественное число сказуемого**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=64) (Грамота.ру)

> ...опорное слово подлежащего (*ряд, большинство, множество* и т. п.), представляя собой существительное в форме единственного числа, фактически означает множество предметов или явлений как совокупность.

Comment: Да. Я неверно сформулировал, вопрос именно в ребятах, волках, музыкантах. ТО есть  все это подлежащее?

Comment: @Ajgy Считаю, что да. Без ребят, волков и музыкантов уходит смысл. Они по сути являются субъектами, хоть и грамматически стоят в Р. п.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: Александр. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему на этом сайте: https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/handbook?id=233 
 по-другому выделяют?

Comment: @Ajgy Поэтому я и написал, что вопрос дискуссионный. У разных лингвистов разные мнения. Подл. может быть выражено сложными сочетаниями, где "в качестве опорного слова могут выступать.... существительные, имеющие значение количества, объема, меры, **совокупности** (куча, толпа, ватага, стая, вереница и т.п.)" ([Русский язык для школьников](https://cooksy.ru/articles/kogda-podlezhaschee-sostoit-iz-2-slov/)). "Подл. включает слова СТАЯ, ГРУППА, ТРОЙКА, ДЕСЯТОК, СОТНЯ и т.п." ([grammatika-rus.ru](https://grammatika-rus.ru/soglasovanie-podlezhashhego-s-sobiratelnym-kolichestvennym-znacheniem/)).

Comment: Теперь понятно, спасибо.

Comment: @Ajgy Спасибо за вопрос, было интересно!